# Can someone help me calculate mean and sd for all my rows from selected columns

Tags: r

Within my dataset there are many rows that are code markers and then many columns i believe we're only interested in column 2-96 as column 1 is the code markers names. 2-50 is c3 repititions and 50 - 96 is c4. For each code marker i am meant to produce a mean and sd from their c3 and c4 repetitions so the out put is a mean and sd of c3 and c4 for every code marker (row name). the column names are not just c3 for all the c3 repetitions it goes c3_1, c3_1.1, etc. I would like it to be one function for both sd and mean for both c3 and c4. I was thinking that probably means using the column number would work better (as mention earlier).

I managed to create this code however it does what i need but for columns not rows, is this a simple fix?

df1[,lapply(.SD, function(x) return(c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))), .SDcols = colnames(df1)[2:6]]

Comment: can you try and follow these guidelines to help us answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example - cheers

Comment: Can you show the 'df1'.  Also, what are those x1.0 and x1.1.  Based on your descriptioin, I guess you want to split into two groups 'c3' and 'c4'

Comment: yeah i want split into c3 and c4 but was demonstrating that all the columns names are different and ```df1 <- data.table(df) ```

Comment: How did you read the dataset.  Perhaps you have used `header = FALSE` in `read.csv/read.table`? because the column names are first row now and it created `factor` columns

Comment: You can check my updated code

Comment: the `str` you updated shows may be it is a `dat.a.table` with column names as numbers?

Comment: Did you convert to `character` class while setting the column name `as.character(unlist(df1[1, -1]))`

Comment: Please try from your original dataset without the conversion.  I think you made a lot of changes  by converting to data.table etc.  Please start on a fresh R session.  Load the data as data.frame (no data.table conversion) and apply the code.  Also, when you use `read.csv`, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and `skip = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
 summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
     sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212050/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-can-someone-help-me-calculate-mean-and-sd-for-all).